# damped and undamped oscillation graph comparison

Tags: homework-and-exercises, harmonic-oscillator

[image]I have been trying to solve a problem which compares the two motion.
If the undamped free harmonic oscillator motion is $ x=A\sin\omega_{o}t$. So the corresponding motion in case of damped motion will be $ x=Ae^{-\frac{\gamma t}{2}}\sin\omega_{1}t$ is what I think. where $ \omega_{1}=\sqrt{\omega_{o}^{2}-\frac{\gamma^{2}}{4}} $ .I want to prove the maximum of the first graph is ahead of the second graph by $ \phi=\frac{1}{2Q}$ where $Q=\frac{\omega_{1}}{\gamma}$. $\gamma$ is the damping resistance. 
I tried to solve by finding the maximum value of the 2nd function for a value of t. then difference of the phase of the two graph should give me the answer. But the answer does not match.

Comment: Since you have the graphs, could you post them and point out what the problem is?

Comment: is it ok if post a photo of the graph. I do not know how to draw by software.

Comment: yes, if the picture is a reasonable size.

Comment: How is $\lambda $ related to $t$, are they independent? Is $\lambda $ a constant?

Comment: Really sorry i did some typing mistakes

Comment: I agree that the damped equation will peak before the non-damped equation, but your graph shows they both have the same period which is not true if $ \omega_{1}=\sqrt{\omega_{o}^{2}-\frac{\gamma^{2}}{4}} $

Comment: if it is lightly damped they $\omega $ and $\omega_{1}$ can be considered to be the same?

Comment: I think, $Q = \frac{\omega_0}{\gamma}$. Does that solve your problem?